# $f(x)={1\over (x-1)(x+2)}$ Taylor series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find Taylor series around $x_0=0$ for: $$f(x)={1\over (x-1)(x+2)}=(\text{By a hint\by simple algebra}){1\over 3}\left[{1\over x-1}-{1\over x+2}\right]$$. Check where the series converges to the function $f$. 
I am really weak in this kind of questions. Thorough explanation are more then welcome. Short explanation and hints are welcome as well.

Comment: You know the series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$. For $\frac{1}{2+x}$ rewrite as $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}}$ and use the series for $\frac{1}{1-t}$ with $t=-\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: I saw others use those form... I have not yet understood why it is more helpful or easy when we have ${1\over a+x}$??

Comment: We get (when $a\ne 0$) a geometric series for $\frac{1}{a+x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n ={1 \over 1-x} \ , \ |x|<1 $$

We have: $$-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n ={1 \over x-1} \ , \ |x|<1$$

$${1 \over x+2}={1 \over 2}{1 \over 1-(-x/2)}={1 \over 2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (-\frac{x}{2} \right )^n\quad ,\ |x|<2$$

Since the series of the sum is the sum of the series we have:

$$f(x)={1 \over 3} \left [ {1 \over x-1} - {1 \over x+2}\right ]= {1 \over 3}  \left [ -\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n - {1 \over 2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left (-\frac{x}{2} \right )^n\right ]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left [-{1 \over 3} \left ( 1 +{1 \over 2}\left (-{1 \over 2}\right )^n\right ) \right ] x^n$$

for $|x|<1$.

EDIT:

The first formula is the geometric series.

Let $x \in \Bbb{R}$ with $|x|<1$. Put $s_n=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n$, note that:

$$x s_n=x+x^2+\cdots +x^{n+1}$$
Therefore:

$$s_n-xs_n=1-x^{n+1}$$

$$s_n={1-x^{n+1}\over 1-x}$$

Since $|x|<1$, $x^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, which gives:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1-x^{n+1}\over 1-x}={1 \over 1-x}$$

Comment: The fact that ${1\over 1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{t^n}$ is a result of what? I can't find it in the notes... Is it a Taylor expansion? 
By the way, thank you. You are helping a lot.

Comment: Check my edit. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n$ is the Taylor expansion of $f(t)={1 \over 1-t}$, although I obtained it above by another method (recall that the Taylor expansion is unique).